# move assignment to object with const value

Tags: c++, c++11, move

I have a struct like this:

```
struct OBJ {
  int x;
  const int y;
  OBJ& operator=(OBJ &&oth)
  {
    y = oth.y; // this is disallowed
    return *this;
  }
}
```

And an example code

```
void func() {
  static OBJ obj;
  OBJ other; // random values
  if(conditon)
    obj = std::move(other); //move
}
```

I understand this as `obj` is **Non const** OBJ with const member `y`. I can't change just y but I should be able to change whole object (call destructor and constructor). Is this possible or the only proper solution is to remove my `const` before `y`, and remember to don't change by accident?

I need to store my `static obj` between `func` call but if condition is true i want to move other object in place of this static object.

Comment: [Off Topic] `obj = std::move(OBJ());` is not needed.  `OBJ()` is already a rvalue so `obj = OBJ();` does the same thing.

Comment: Use a [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Comment: You will need to write your own move assignment operator (and while you're at it, the other special member functions)

Comment: @NathanOliver this code is just example in real `func` this object allready exist and I want move it not construct!

Comment: And perhaps you should [read a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) as well, because you have a constructor, and those should not return anything.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I update question. I made mistake. I want assigment move, not constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest moving to `std::unique_ptr`:

```
void func() {
  static std::unique_ptr<OBJ> obj = std::make_unique<OBJ>();
  std::unique_ptr<OBJ> other = std::make_unique<OBJ>(); // random values
  if(condition)
    obj = std::move(other); //move
}
```

This should be your choice in many cases where there is a need to move something that cannot be moved, to hold an unknown polymorphic type or any other case where you cannot deal with the actual type.

Comment: This will work with const values? It look like it do the work! Excellent solution!

Comment: @S.R it should work. well, you can see it does. I would advise, objectively as I can, to mark it as the accepted answer :-)

Comment: @amir-krish Yes I will accept it as soon as I test it. I have another question Can I tell compiler to accept my struct only as uniq_ptr? So the only way is generate uniq pointer. I wonder about private constructors and make_obj function as a friend.

Comment: @S.R by the master of RValues himself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17135547/2085626 another option can be found here: http://seanmiddleditch.com/enabling-make_unique-with-private-constructors/

Answer (score 2):

You're doing constructors wrong. Constructors should *initialize*, not assign:

```
OBJ(OBJ &&oth) : y(oth.y) {}
//             ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, constructors cannot `return *this`, since they have no return type.

An assignment operator for your class doesn't make sense since the class has unassignable members (namely constants). (You could of course write a custom assignment that doesn't modify the const member, but then you'd have a truly weird class that has extremely surprising behaviour.)

Comment: sorry I edit question. There shuld be `operator=` not a constructor. Sorry for the mess

Comment: @S.R: Updated the answer, too.

Comment: Yea but this is still for constructor, not assignment. @kerrek-sb

Comment: @S.R: Second paragraph :-)

Comment: Ok. So you are say that i **have to** remove `const` in my variable `y`. The question is how to change the whole static object which contains const member (`y`). Not how to construct it first time.

Comment: @S.R: If the member is not const, assignment works as expected (i.e. member-wise).

Answer (score 2):

What about writing the move-assignment operator this way:

```
OBJ& operator=(OBJ&& other) {
    this->~OBJ();
    new(this) OBJ(other.x, other.y);
    return *this;
}
```

You would also need a constructor:

```
OBJ(const int x, const int y)
    : x(x), y(y)
{
}
```

Comment: Isn't it UB to placement-new over a non-dynamic object with const members?!

Comment: Well, this solution is by large part inspired by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39382728/1003701 The question is about `std::launder` and it seems that launder is the way to fully employ technique mentioned in my answer without getting into Undefined Behaviour lands. See also: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder

Comment: @MiroslavMares Nice, but is this safe when I have no trivial member in my struct?

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder looks great but it's c++17 I need C++14 / C+11 solution.

Comment: @S.R Is it thinkable to modify the struct definition to remove the "`const`"? If so, removing it and enforcing constness of the `y` member variable by making it private and setting up getters/setters might be an attractive possibility.

Comment: @S.R - This is terribly unsafe if the "reconstruction" can possibly fail with an exception. Then you have a zombie object - an object that is alive but dead.

Comment: @BoPersson Good point, one could end with a static variable, which was destructed but constructor did throw, leaving it in an uninitialized state.

Comment: @S.R Worse than what Bo described, unless the constructor is noexcept, you can (and will) potentially destroy the same object (the original `this`) *twice*. Scope has no clue you manually already fired the destructor, so throwing out of this function on an exception from the constructor invoked via placement-new is a huge problem.

Comment: For now I removed `const`, but I don't like this code. This variable should be const. It's not changing but moving. (Old is destructed, new just changing place in memory, so logically this should work in my opinion). I am waiting for std::launder.