# Implement C++ assignment operator in terms of constructor

Tags: c++, copy-and-swap, rule-of-zero, rule-of-five

### Background

Suppose you want to implement a resource-managing class in C++.  You cannot use the [Rule of Zero](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-zero) or [Rule of Five Defaults](https://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2014/03/a-concern-about-rule-of-zero.html), so you actually need to implement copy and move constructor, copy and move assignment operator, and destructor.  In this question, Iʼll use [`Box`](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/o4E8j7qK5) as an example, but this can apply to lots of different types.

```cpp
// Store object on heap but keep value semantics
// Moved-from state has null elem; otherwise should have value
// Only valid operations on moved-from state are assignment and destruction
// Assignment only offers a basic exception guarantee
template <typename T>
class Box {
public:
    using value_type = T;

    // Default constructor
    Box() : elem{new value_type} {}
    // Accessor
    value_type& get() { return *elem; }
    value_type const& get() const { return *elem; }

    // Rule of Five
    Box(Box const& other) : elem{new value_type{*(other.elem)}} {};
    Box(Box&& other) : elem{other.elem}
    {
        other.elem = nullptr;
    };
    Box& operator=(Box const& other)
    {
        if (elem) {
            *elem = *(other.elem);
        } else {
            elem = new value_type{*(other.elem)};
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Box& operator=(Box&& other)
    {
        delete elem;
        elem = other.elem;
        other.elem = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }
    ~Box()
    {
        delete elem;
    }

    // Swap
    friend void swap(Box& lhs, Box& rhs)
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(lhs.elem, rhs.elem);
    }
private:
    T* elem;
};
```

(Note that a better `Box` implementation would have more features like `noexcept` and `constexpr` functions, `explicit` forwarding constructors based on `value_type`ʼs constructors, allocator support, etc; here Iʼm implementing just whatʼs necessary for the question and the tests.  It might also save some code with `std::unique_ptr`, but that would make it a less-clear example)

Note that the assignment operators share lots of code with each other, with their respective constructors, and with the destructor.  This would be somewhat lessened if I didnʼt want to allow assignment to moved-from `Box`en, but would be more apparent in a more complicated class.

#### Digression: Copy-and-Swap

One standard way of handling this is with the [Copy-And-Swap Idiom (also in this context called the Rule of Four and a Half)](https://mropert.github.io/2019/01/07/copy_swap_20_years/), which also gets you a strong exception guarantee if `swap` is `nothrow`:

```cpp
    // Copy and Swap (Rule of Four and a Half)
    Box& operator=(Box other)  // Take `other` by value
    {
        swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }
```

This allows you to write only one assignment operator (taking `other` by value lets the compiler move the other to the parameter if possible, and does the copying for you if necessary), and that assignment operator is simple (assuming you already have `swap`).  However, as the linked article says, that has issues such as doing an extra allocation and keeping extra copies of the contents around during the operation.

### The Idea

What I havenʼt seen before is something Iʼll call a Destroy-and-Initialize assignment operator.  Since weʼre already doing all the work in the constructor, and an assigned-to version of the object should be identical to a copy-constructed one, why not use the constructor, as follows:

```cpp
    // Destroy-and-Initialize Assignment Operator
    template <typename Other>
    Box& operator=(Other&& other)
    requires (std::is_same_v<Box, std::remove_cvref_t<Other>>)
    {
        this->~Box();
        new (this) Box{std::forward<Other>(other)};
        return *std::launder(this);
    }
```

This still does an extra allocation like Copy-and-Swap does, but only in the copy assignment case instead of the move assignment case, and it does it *after* destroying one of the copies of `T`, so it doesnʼt fail under resource constraints.

### Questions

1. Has this been proposed before, and if so where can I read more about it?
2. Is this UB in some cases, such as if the `Box` is a subobject of something else, or is it allowed to destroy and re-construct subobjects?
3. Does this have any downsides I havenʼt mentioned, like not being `constexpr` compatible?
4. Are there other options to avoid assignment operator code reuse, like this and the Rule of Four and a Half, when you canʼt just `= default` them?

Comment: This approach will have UB if any of the non-static member of the class are `const` qualified or of a reference type: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58415092/4342498

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, but nothing else would work *either*, unless you want to special-case the handling of that member and it makes sense to have that not change on assignment.

Comment: That approach will cause invalid object if copy constructor throws.

Comment: @Phil1970 Ah, youʼre right, and at least in my example `Box` thereʼs no way to avoid it without just specifying that it requires `T` be nothrow copy constructible, which isnʼt otherwise required.  And even then since the copy constructor is allocating memory, that might fail.  It could work for *move* assignment in this case, which avoids some of the code reuse but not as much.

Comment: I think that **Copy and swap** is adequate 99% of the time. The extra copy (when required) make the assignment transactional which is generally a good thing. If you really need more control, you can always write the operator yourself.